# Does propene have resonance structures?

Tags: bond, molecular-structure, resonance

Propene is an alkene with a double bond between 2 carbon atoms. $\ce{C3H6}$ may have 2 resonance structures due to 2 possible placings of the double bond. E.g. it can be C=C-C or C-C=C (ignoring hydrogen atoms).

Delocalized electrons are a result of resonance structures. Can propene have delocalized electrons?

Comment: How would the proton move from one side of the molecule to the other? Your resonance structure doesn't take into account every atom in the molecule, just the double bond.

Comment: Do you want to say it should be like $\ce{CH2=CH-CH3 <-> CH2-CH=CH3}$  ?

Comment: @Poutnik Yes that's the structure I was suggesting

Comment: And why, exactly ? Isolated double bonds do not have resonance structures.

Comment: You can't really ignore hydrogen atoms.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Yes it cannot be ignored; I just meant it would be easier to recognise the molecular structures without hydrogen atoms around

Comment: Well, and I meant that hydrogens are the reason why you don't have the resonance that you anticipated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Propene actually fulfil conditions for hyperconjugation (an alfa-CH adjacent to sp2 hybrid C atom) It is a delocalization of sigma bond electrons, also called no bond resonance. Mentioned C-H bond align in plane of the pi orbital. In such situation electrons of the sigma bond can be delocalized into the pi orbital. (Propene does not have resonance structures concerning only pi orbitals, as I suspect you think).

These are 3 "no bond resonance" structures of propene.
[image]
This site has diagrams concerning this problem, including mentioned contributing structures:
[http://www.adichemistry.com/organic/basics/hyperconjugation/hyperconjugation-1.html](https://www.adichemistry.com/organic/basics/hyperconjugation/hyperconjugation-1.html)